# Dynamically modify associative array values in php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Let's assume that I have an array like following:

```
$settings = array(
    "age" => "25",
    "data" => array(
            "name" => "John Dewey",
            "zip_code" => "00000"
        )
);
```

Here's my input:

```
$target_directory = "data.name";    // targets $settings["data"]["name"]
$new_value = "Micheal";    // I want to change 
                           // $settings["data"]["name"] with this value
```

I want something similar to following:

```
$new_array = dont_know_what_to_do($target_directory, $new_value, $settings);
```

A `print_r($new_array)` should return following:

```
Array
(
    [age] => 25
    [data] => Array
        (
            [name] => Micheal,
            "zip_code" => "00000"
        )

)
```

**The change should be totally dynamic**, meaning that `data.zip_code = "98985"` should also change only the zip code value from 00000 to 98985, and so on...

Comment: Where's the code you have tried?

Comment: I tried to explode(".", $target_directory); but I am stuck on what to do next?

Comment: Only the in the data keys are updated?

Comment: Try my answer. If it works

Comment: You mean, "Only the data keys are updated?"? If so... 
Then yes. But if I go another tree down, let's say data.name.first_name = $new_value. then it should alter only ["data"]["name"]["first_name"] = $new_value;

Comment: @ArifBillah I've seen you profile, why you accept none answer of any of your qustion.

Comment: @Kris Roofe I didn't know about that tick mark other than the upvote and downvote buttons. I always used to click on the upvote and it would say: Once you earn enough reputation, your upvote will be shown publicly.

Now that I know of that tick mark. I am going to accept answers from previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the dynamic set funciton, you can use it set any depth. **[Demo here](https://eval.in/720506)** for you question.

```
function set($settings, $target_directory, $new_value)
{
  $array = explode('.', $target_directory);
  $ref = &$settings;
  while($v = current($array))
  {
    $ref = &$ref[$v];
    next($array);
  }
  $ref = $new_value;
  return $settings;
}
```

Comment: Oh! that & sign I have never know of... did it all. Thank you so very much. Learnt something new yet important.

Comment: @ArifBillah for php & operator refet to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: That's a whole lot of information. Will have to study for quite a long. Thank you again for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$settings = array(
    "age" => "25",
    "data" => array(
            "name" => "John Dewey",
            "zip_code" => "00000"
        )
);
$new_value = "Micheal"; 
$settings["data"]["name"] = $new_value;
print_r($settings);
```

Comment: It needs to be completely dynamic. You have used some static method. And please targeting like this data.name is needed. Mind reviewing the question? and hopefully giving an answer?

Comment: data.name means... data is a javascript  object am i right?

Comment: Yes, kind of... I want it to work like Javascript targeting but in php.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In your main function
public function something() {
    $settings = array(
     "age" => "25",
     "data" => array(
        "name" => "John Dewey",
        "zip_code" => "00000"
      )
    );

   $target = 'data.name';
   $input = 'Other Name'

  $new_arr = dont_know_what_to_do($target_dir, $input);

  print_r($new_arr);        
}


//Create new function
public function dont_know_what_to_do($settings, $target, $input) {
  $key = explode('.', $target)
  return $settings['data'][$key[1]] = $input;
}
```

Comment: Will work, but if I go another tree down, let's say data.name.first_name = $new_value. then it should alter only ["data"]["name"]["first_name"] = $new_value;