# PHP - build array from string and values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

How can I build an array from string and values ?

For exemple :

```
            string              |        value
                                |   
objectId                        |   19
location.street                 |   Rue des clochets
translations.fr.idTranslation   |   4
```

And the result must be :

```
[
    'objectId' => 19,
    'location' => [
        'street' => 'Rue des clochets'
    ],
    'translations' => [
        'fr' => [
            idTranslation => 4
        ],
    ]
]
```

Obiviously, if the key already exists, it is complete, not duplicate.

Like : 
    translation.fr.country  |  France

The array will become :

```
[
    'object' => 19,
    'location' => [
        'street' => 'Rue des clochets'
    ],
    'translations' => [
        'fr' => [
            'idTranslation' => 4,
            'country'       => 'France'
        ],
    ]
]
```

I think, using explode is the good way but I don't find the good syntax.

The head of my method is :

```
 public function buildArray($key, $value) {

 }
```

I call this method in a foreach.

And the array is a property.

Thank's for help.

Comment: I'm using PHP sorry

Comment: [Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41756522/6521116)

Comment: [How to write getter/setter to access multi-level array by key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27929875/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function buildArray($key, $value) {   
  $keys = explode('.', $key);

  $x = count($keys) - 1;
  $temp = array($keys[$x] => $value);
  for($i = $x-1; $i >= 0; $i--)
  {
    $temp = array($keys[$i] => $temp);
  }
  return $temp
}
```

Something like this should work. Please appologize if it does not run without some work of you, it is untested, but it seems to work https://3v4l.org/3HBAY.
Of course this will give you one array per key/value pair. You will have to merge the returning array (`array_merge_recursive`) with your result in your foreach.

Comment: Why the downvote? Can this person please explain what should be wrong with this answer? If there is a reason for a downvote, I will gladly improve my answer or even delete it. But without a comment I see no sense in it.

Comment: Thank's that's work. (Indeed, I need to use array_merge_recursive)

Comment: @NicolasLamblin Glad to help you. Could you please tell me what you fixed, so i can correct my answer (for future visitors).

Comment: I saw the answer without the comment about array_merge_recursive. I used array_merge and keys weren't saved in the array. With array_merge_recursive the problem is solved.

Comment: @NicolasLamblin yeah I saw that a little bit late. Thank you for your feedback I appreciate it. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code below, you can also tinker with it at https://3v4l.org/sLvXp

```
<?php

$input = "objectId                        |   19
location.street                 |   Rue des clochets
translations.fr.idTranslation   |   4";

$output = [];

$lines = explode("\n", $input);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $cols = explode("|", $line);
    $key = trim($cols[0]);
    $value = trim($cols[1]);
    $indices = explode('.', $key);
    $first = array_shift($indices);
    if (!isset($output[$first]))
        $output[$first] = [];
    $target = &$output[$first];
    foreach ($indices as $index) {
        if (!isset($target[$index])) {
            $target[$index] = [];
            $target = &$target[$index];
        }
    }
    $target = $value;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Thank's, that's work. The result is the same as Doktor OSwaldo.